# UDF to insert a text string in to each row of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I've been searching high and low for an answer and I can't seem to find anything that points me in the right direction.

I need to create a UDF that will extract each word of a text string and return a table with each word of the string in a separate row.

The UDF is only able to take in one variable '@mytext'.

We can assume that the text string is separated by a single space and may contain commas or periods.

For example, "don’t worry about failures, worry about the chances you miss when you don’t even try." would need to return a table with each word on a separate row of a column without the commas or periods present.

I'm figuring that the text string would need to be separated with a common value that could be used to separate each word for insert, but I could totally be wrong.

Any help with this would be really appreciated!

Based on what I've said so far, here is my far from complete code that I'm not too sure how to proceed with

```
create function [dbo].[textConverter]
(
    @mytext nvarchar(max)
)
returns @text_string table
    (
        word nvarchar
    )
as
begin

set @mytext = replace(@mytext, 'what needs to be changed', 'what it needs to be changed too')

--insert string to table

end
```

**EDIT**

I've checked out a couple of links and uncovered a little more information on this, I've now got this code. However it exits with an error. The example that was used in the article I found the code on used numbers in the insert so maybe this is the issue??

```
create function [dbo].[textConverter]
(
    @mytext varchar(max)
)
returns @text_string table
    (
        word nvarchar
    )
as
begin

--Change string to be seperated by commas
set @mytext = replace(@mytext, ' ', ',')
set @mytext = replace(@mytext, '.',',')

--Eliminate double commas
set @mytext = replace(@mytext, ',,', ',')

declare @name nvarchar(255)
declare @pos int

while CHARINDEX(',', @mytext) > 0
begin
select @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @mytext)
select @name = SUBSTRING(@mytext, 1, @pos-1)

insert into @text_string
select @name

select @mytext = SUBSTRING(@mytext, @pos+1, LEN(@mytext)-@pos)
end

insert into @text_string
select @mytext

return
end

--To use function
select * from dbo.textConverter('don’t worry about failures, worry about the chances you miss when you don’t even try.')
```

Comment: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/

Comment: What RDBMS? Your syntax looks like SQL-Server.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I should've mentioned. Yes it is SQL-Server

Comment: Did you search? At all? http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted some of the code from http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings as my situation meant that the delimiter couldn't specified as input. I could only use on input and that was the text string. As such, the following worked for me:

```
create function [dbo].[textConverter]
( 
    @string nvarchar(max)
) 
returns @output table(splitdata nvarchar(max) 
) 
begin 

--Change string to be seperated by commas
set @string = replace(@string, ' ', ',')
set @string = replace(@string, '.',',')

--Eliminate double commas
set @string = replace(@string, ',,', ',')

    declare @start int, @end int
    select @start = 1, @end = charindex(',',@string)

    while @start < len(@string) + 1 
    begin
        if @end = 0
            set @end = len(@string) + 1

        insert into @output (splitdata)
        values(substring(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        set @start = @end + 1
        set @end = charindex(',', @string, @start)

    end
    return
end
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answer below, It is not in complete shape, but can be developed into a user defined function.

```
Declare @Sentence Varchar(max) = 'don’t worry about failures, worry about the chances you miss when you don’t even try.'
Set     @Sentence = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(@Sentence,',',' '),'.',' '),'  ',' '),'   ',' ')


Declare @e int = (Select Len(@Sentence) - Len(Replace(@Sentence,' ','')))
Declare @s int = 1
Declare @Result Table(id int identity(1,1),Words varchar(max))

--Select @s,@e
While @s <= @e
begin
    Insert into @Result
    Select Left(@Sentence,Charindex(' ',@Sentence,1)-1)

    Set @Sentence = Substring(@Sentence,Charindex(' ',@Sentence,1) + 1,Len(@Sentence) )

Set @s = @s + 1
End

Insert into @Result
Select @Sentence

Select * from @Result
```

Result

```
----+-----------
id  |Words
----+-----------
1   |don’t
2   |worry
3   |about
4   |failures  
5   |worry
6   |about
7   |the
8   |chances
9   |you
10  |miss
11  |when
12  |you
13  |don’t
14  |even
15  |try 
----+-----------
```